# Django models.FileField - store only the file name not any paths or folder references

Tags: python, django, filefield

I'm using Django's Admin site to manage some data - but not building a webapp. I need the file upload field to store only the file name in the database.

Right now I can get absolute paths like:
/Users/me/uploads/file.png

Or using the upload_to parameter get something like this in the database:
uploads/file.png

How can I get it to be this:
file.png

EDIT:

I'm taking the sqlite database and using in another client - so having any paths in the db entry doesn't make sense in my case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `upload_to` arg of the `FileField` can be a callable. see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

If you really need to only store the file name, I think you can do something like this. I did'nt try myself but I think it works.

```
def only_filename(instance, filename):
    return filename

class MyModel(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=only_filename)
```

Answer (score 12):

I would keep the FileField and use python [os.path.basename](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) to extract the filename.

This can be encapsulated with a property

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
   file = models.FileField(...)

   @property
   def filename(self):
       return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

Comment: The `os.path.basename` is what you're looking for, but luc's answer here really encapsulates it in a very django/pythonesque way.

Comment: This actually won't help - we're using the sqllite database in another client so I'd like any paths taken out completely.

Comment: I think it is more clear to post the edit into another answer